# Protected routung in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

***Aim*** : I have user logged in as ADMIN, user is in localstorage. Now i want to check
if User === "admin" return the Component else Redirect to main page.

***Problem :*** Whenever i try to access the component (logged in as ADMIN) it Redirects me to main application page. What it should do is to let me in.

Here is the code, i think the problem is in If statement.

```
  function App() {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer.cart);
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile"));

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/updateProduct/:name/:id">

          <Navbar cart={cart} user={user} />
          if(user?.result?.role !== "admin") {<Redirect to="/" />} //here it is misbehaving
          <ProductUpdate />
          <Footer />

        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
  }
export default App;
```

Note. I have multiple components here, So how do i do it.

Comment: please console the value of `user?.result?.role`. What's it showing?

Comment: as u mentioned `ADMIN` so your check should be `user?.result?.role !== "ADMIN"`

Comment: taken from console. "User's Role = > admin" .I mentioned ADMIN just to highlight

Comment: can u create a https://codesandbox.io/ of your issue?

Comment: :(  its a big project. User's data in localstorage coming from backend.

Comment: `if(user?.result?.role !== "admin") { console.log('here');<Redirect to="/" />}`

is 'here' showing in the console ?

Comment: Thanks for help. I did it using ternary operator. "IF statement" do not work inside <Route />                 <Route path="/updateProduct/:name/:id">
          <Navbar cart={cart} user={user} />
          {user?.result?.role !== "admin" ? (
            <Redirect to="/" />
          ) : (
            <ProductUpdate />
          )}
          <Footer />
        </Route>

Comment: I've done something like this, you could create a new component that render the route or not, depending on user object

Comment: great, that's what i was doubting about :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i concern, you need to use ternary operator or short circuit inside `route`.
You can use this by consoling the output.

```
if(user?.result?.role !== "admin") { 
  console.log('here');
  <Redirect to="/" />};
}
```

check if 'here' is showing in the console.